# In the Raises section of the docstring of a function, should the exceptions raised indirectly be listed too?

Tags: python, exception, docstring, raise

For example, for:

```py
def foo(a):
    if a == 10:
        raise FooError
    return 1 / a
```

Should the docstring for `foo` contain something like:

```py
"""Raises:
    FooError: if a is equal to 10.
    ZeroDivisionError: if a is equal to 0.
"""
```

Or should it just list the exceptions that the function itself raises, i. e. `FooError`? Any insights as to what's better are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: List all exceptions relevant to users of your code, regardless of implementation.

---

A docstring is directed at the *user* of a function/class. Just like a proper class interface, a docstring should not be concerned with implementation details of a function/class. The content of a docstring should only reflect the *what*, not the *how*.

This means that whether an error is documented should *not* differ between different implementations of the same thing.

---

Consider moving the error-raising code to a helper:

```py
class Bar:
    def foo(self, a):
        if a == 10:
            raise FooBarError
        return 1 / a

    def bar(self, a):
        self._reject(a, 10)
        return 1 / a

    def _reject(self, value, forbidden):
        if value == forbidden:
            raise FooBarError
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are functionally equivalent to client code. Their internal validation logic is a mere implementation detail that does not change how to use them.

Comment: I see your point, and it makes sense. However, I was wondering, being new to docstrings (yeah... ) if there wasn't already an automatic way in which, having raises be documented for functions called in `bar` (ie `_reject`), those wouldn't also surface in `bar`. I guess that depends on how you access the documentation. And I'm not really fixated on that.

Comment: I made a little test with the `help` function and, from what I can see, it doesn't surface info found in the docstrings of functions called in the implementation of the function passed to it. So calling `help(bar)` wouldn't tell you about what's in `_reject`'s docstring.

Comment: But then again, I don't know if tools like Sphinx do.

Comment: @AndreiToroplean Resolving the call graph in Python is highly complex, moreso inferring types and exceptions from this. Sphinx does not attempt to do so.